# Ada: Access first element in Real_Matrix with one row and one column

Tags: ada

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

I have a Real_Matrix with one row and one column. I would like to evaluate the value of the single element on row one, column one. I'm getting an error when I try to access the Matrix using the: Matrix(I, J) syntax. See below:

**CODE**

```
with Ada.Numerics.Real_Arrays; use Ada.Numerics.Real_Arrays;
with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Matrix is

   ------------------------------------
   -- Real_Matrix Division Operation --
   ------------------------------------

   function "/" (Left  : Real_Matrix;
                 Right : Real_Matrix) return Real_Matrix
   is
   begin
      return Left * Inverse(Right);
   end "/";

   α : Real_Matrix := ( ( Integer'First => 1.0 ),
                        ( Integer'First => 2.0 ) );
   β : Real_Matrix := ( ( Integer'First => 3.0 ),
                        ( Integer'First => 4.0 ) );

begin

   -- This operation returns an matrix with one row and one column --

   Put_Line(Float'Image(((Transpose(α) * α) / (Transpose(β) * β))(Integer'First, Integer'First))); -- Error: Missing "," --

end Matrix;
```

Comment: Can you add the type definition of Real_Matrix ?

Comment: Also, break it down as a diagnostic technique. Assign the matrix operation result to an intermediate variable. Index that as a separate operation. See which part fails.

Comment: Note that `Integer'First` is `-2147483648`, whereas you might have wanted a `1` or `0` instead.

Comment: @NWS, `Real_Matrix` is declared in `Ada.Numerics.Real_Arrays` (ARM G.3.1(31)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a real language lawyer to tell you whether this is a compiler failure or proper behaviour, but your code will compile if you force the compiler to recognise that the `/` operation produces a `Real_Matrix`:

```ada
Put_Line
  (Float'Image 
     (Real_Matrix'((Transpose(α) * α) / (Transpose(β) * β))
        (Integer'First, Integer'First)));
```

---

When I tried this, I got a Constraint_Error; so I tried @BrianDrummond’s suggestion,

```ada
γ : constant Real_Matrix := (Transpose(α) * α) / (Transpose(β) * β);
```

and it turns out that `γ’First (1)` is -2147483648, whereas `γ’First (2)` is 1 (this is GNAT GPL 2016 on macOS Sierra).

Further investigation: I’m pretty sure this is a bug in GNAT’s `Inverse`.
[ARM G.3.1(72)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-G-3-1.html#p71) says

> This function returns a matrix B such that A * B is (nearly) equal to the unit matrix. The index ranges of the result are A'Range(2) and A'Range(1). Constraint_Error is raised if A'Length(1) is not equal to A'Length(2). Constraint_Error is raised if the matrix A is ill-conditioned.

and GNAT’s implementation is

```ada
function Inverse (A : Real_Matrix) return Real_Matrix is
  (Solve (A, Unit_Matrix (Length (A))));
```

where `Solve` (same reference, (70)) says

> This function returns a matrix Y such that X is (nearly) equal to A * Y. This is the standard mathematical operation for solving several sets of linear equations. The index ranges of the result are A'Range(2) and X'Range(2). Constraint_Error is raised if A'Length(1), A'Length(2), and X'Length(1) are not equal. Constraint_Error is raised if the matrix A is ill-conditioned.

and `Unit_Matrix` (same reference, (79)) is

```ada
function Unit_Matrix (Order            : Positive;
                      First_1, First_2 : Integer := 1) return Real_Matrix;
```

Notice the default values for `First_1`, `First_2`!

Comment: In your example, to access the element in the array 'y' the following syntax works:

Value_Of_Element_In_y := y(y'First(1), y'First(2)

Comment: That’s not an example, that’s a quotation from the reference manual.